# Whose properties does data binding from code-behind really expose?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

When we use DataContext of another control, we can access its properties like Value below.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="my_prog" Height="10" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=my_slider}"/>
```

But I am confused when we assign data context from code, shouldn't we access its properties as well? But in the example below, the data context is a list of cars but how can we access `Speed` property which belongs to the `car`,  not to the `list`? This example does show the speed correctly.

```
public partial class CarsView : Window
{
    public CarsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var cars = new List<Car>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            Car car = new Car();
            cars.Add(car);
            car.Speed = i * 10;
        }

        this.DataContext = cars;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxCars" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="114,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="252">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Speed}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: A Binding with ElementName does not use the DataContext of the control. Besides that, you can use indexers in data binding expressions. Start reading here: [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax). Better however would be to access the Car properties in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl that is bound to the List<Car>. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: How did you bind a `Speed` value?

Comment: did you try `Binding Value.Speed`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski and @Charles, I haven't. This `this.DataContext = cars;` is the only line that does the binding. So I don't know how `Speed`is accessible but it is.

Comment: @zar Please, share your xaml code, it's unclear what are asking about

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski just did.

Comment: @zar Does this help `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Speed}" />`? Because currently you are trying to bind `Speed` property from your data context, which is a `List<Car>()`. I don't think that `Speed` is exist inside this collection itself, it belongs to `Car` object

Comment: Are you sure that Speed is actually a public property and not a field? Otherwise the Binding in the ItemTemplate should just work.

Comment: This binding is working, I am just not sure how since coming from C++ world, we are only passing it a reference/pointer of list object but it can access Speed property which belongs to car!

Comment: @Clemens trying to understand, this example is in a book but it doesn't explain how this works.

Comment: Read the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) article, including the *See also* section. Please also note that this hasn't got anything to do with the programming language you choose. You could as well write that example in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the root element in the `ItemTemplate` (the `TextBlock` in your case) is the current item in the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`, i.e. a `Car` object in this case.

That's why the binding to `Speed` works assuming that `Speed` is a *public property* of the `Car` class.

The `ItemTemplate` is applied to each item in the `ItemsSource`. You can read more about how this works in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: I wish the example in the link you provided would be a little complete, coming from Microsoft. It access `myTodoList` but it's not provided an and not sure where is the data that XAML is displaying.

Comment: @zar: Please clarify your issue. What is our actual question?